# Python Launcher running script with libraries that have not yet been installed. IDLE cannot run script

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, python-idle

Everyone

I'm only a beginner in python, but I have installed the latest version of the python launcher and idle in my mac (running catalina.)

I used to have anaconda installed on my mac a few years ago, and made some scripts using numpy and matplotlib. I have since, deleted anaconda from my computer.

Today, when I tried to run this script, on the default python idle, it did not run, as it did not identify numpy. I quickly realized that I had to install it using pip.

But, for some reason, the program did run when I used the "python launcher." It opened terminal, and even gave me a plot out of it, that I could save and everything.

Why is this? Could I have some insight as to why the python launcher would run this script without having installed the necessary libraries. Could there be remnants of anaconda that the python launcher is using?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Jun  9 12:49:47 2018

@author: x
"""

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(-np.pi/2, np.pi, 40)
c = np.cos(x)
plt.plot(c,'.')
plt.show()
```

Comment: When you tried to run the script using the "default python idle" did you use the command `python <scriptfile>.py` or `python3 <scriptfile>.py`? I suspect that you tried to launch the script using Python2.7, while it was written for Python3.x. Try running `pip list` and then `pip3 list`. I suspect that the modules are installed on Python3.

Comment: I used the python3 command, as following `python3 testingplotting.py` and I got `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testingplotting.py", line 9, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`

Comment: I also ran the `pip3 list` command, and I only had the pip and setuptools packages. nothing else.

Comment: It sounds like you may have more than one version of Python present.  Are you sure you deleted it when you deleted Anaconda?  It's easy to check.  If you start the Python launcher with no arguments, it will start an interactive Python session.  It will print a banner identifying the python version #.  If you start IDLE it will print the same banner right at the top.  If you run a script, the first line of the script (bang line) can override the Python launcher's default version.  You can also import sys and print(sys.version) very early in your script, before you try to import numpy,

Comment: I added a print(sys.version) and I got the following `xxx@xxx-Laptop mypython % python testingplotting.py
2.7.16 (default, Feb 29 2020, 01:55:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.29.20) (-macos10.15-objc-` I also tried running the script using the `python testingplotting.py` command and this time it did work. I'm confused as to why this is the case, because the shebang points to a python3 environment not python2.